# Iterating list json object in golang

Tags: go

I have this piece of code to read a JSON object. I need to easily iterate over all the elements in the 'outputs'/data/concepts key.

Is there a better way to do it?

Also, how can I access the attributes of value:
value.app_id, value.id..etc

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var jsonBytes = []byte(`
{"outputs": [{
          "data": {"concepts": 
                                 [{"app_id": "main",
                                     "id": "ai_GTvMbVGh",
                                     "name": "ancient",
                                     "value": 0.99875855}]
              }}
              ],
 "status": {"code": 10000, "description": "Ok"}}`)


func main() {
    var output map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBytes), &output)
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    for _, value := range output["outputs"].([]interface{}) {
        //fmt.Println(value.(map[string]interface{})["data"].(map[string]interface{})["concepts"]).([]interface{})
        //fmt.Println(value.(map[string]interface{})["data"].(map[string]interface{})["concepts"])
        for _, value := range value.(map[string]interface{})["data"].(map[string]interface{})["concepts"].([]interface{}){
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
    }
    //fmt.Printf("%+v\n", output)
}
```

Comment: your json is invalid.

Comment: oops.fixed the data and the code. Need to know if there is a better way to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way will be to Unmarshal the JSON into an struct and iterate over the values,

```
func main() {

        var output StructName


err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBytes), &output)
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    for _, value := range output.Outputs {
        for _, val := range value.Data.Concepts {
            fmt.Printf("AppId:%s\nID:%s\nname:%s\nvalue:%f", val.AppID, val.ID, val.Name, val.Value)
        }
    }
}

type StructName struct {
    Outputs []struct {
        Data struct {
            Concepts []struct {
                AppID string  `json:"app_id"`
                ID    string  `json:"id"`
                Name  string  `json:"name"`
                Value float64 `json:"value"`
            } `json:"concepts"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"outputs"`
    Status struct {
        Code        int    `json:"code"`
        Description string `json:"description"`
    } `json:"status"`
}
```